# java keyword extraction

Tags: java, nlp, keyword

Is there a simple to use Java library that can take a String and return a set of Strings which are the keywords/keyphrases.

It doesn't have to be particularly clever, just use stop words and stemming to match keywords.

I am looking at the KEA package http://code.google.com/p/kea-algorithm/ but I can't figure out how to use their code.

Ideally something simple which has a little example documentation would be good. In the meantime I will set about writing this myself!

EDIT: When I say I can't see how to figure out how to use their code, I mean I can't see a simple way. The individiual classes by themselves have useful methods that will do much of the work.

Comment: What do you mean keyword/keyphrases? like a regex inside the string or something?

Comment: no .... keywords that a search engine would recognise, I want to extract keywords from news articles and get a list of similar articles from different news sites (I know there are lots of existing services that do that ... it's just a bit of fun and learning for me).

Comment: Nice I love that idea.  You should look for/write an algorithm that calculates word/phrase frequencies

Comment: @Trevor I've decided to 'cheat' and I'm using Alchemy API http://www.alchemyapi.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly old question and probably the OP has already solved his problem, but putting it here for others who may stumble upon the question looking for how to use KEA.

For KEA, you will need a training set - some of your documents will need to have keywords already set. The training data consists of a directory of documents (.txt files) and corresponding keywords files (.key files), with one keyword per line. You train KEA on this set, then use the model to extract keywords on the rest of your documents, which are in another directory of .txt files. KEA will write out corresponding .key files in this directory.

For more information, take a look at one or more of the following:

1) The KEA source distribution has a TestKEA.java class which shows how to extract keywords from a small test corpus. The README has details on the directory format required.

2) This blog post has (a somewhat terse IMO) instructions on how to use KEA.

http://kea-pranay.blogspot.com/2010/02/kea-key-extraction-algorithm.html

3) My blog post which I wrote up last weekend while trying to learn how to generate keywords from a corpus I had (which were already manually annotated with keywords). It has Python code to pre-process data to the way KEA expects it, Scala (KEA provides a Java API) code to train and run the extractor, and Python code to do analyze and visualize the generated keywords.

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2014/08/keyword-extraction-with-kea.html

Answer (score 0):

You might try the Porter Stemming algorithm: the java version is at http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt and the main page is at http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/. Its old, but doesn't do a bad job.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it gives rather poor results. The KEA library includes an implementation. I have actually decided to ignore stemming for the time being.

Comment: All good: glad to help. Do let me know if you come back to it: I'd be curious what you end up using.